# Why are these two functions not equivalent?

Tags: numpy

This is taken from the [Keras sample code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py):

```
    def sample(preds, temperature=1.0):
        preds = np.asarray(preds).astype('float64')
        preds = np.log(preds) / temperature
        exp_preds = np.exp(preds)
        preds = exp_preds / np.sum(exp_preds)
        probas = np.random.multinomial(1, preds, 1)
        return np.argmax(probas)
```

This is an attempt to simplify the above code:

```
    def sample(p, temperature=1.0):
        p = np.exp(np.log(p) / temperature)
        p = np.random.multinomial(1, p / p.sum(), 1)
        return np.argmax(p)
```

However the second one fails with this error:

```
File "z.py", line 75, in sample
    p = np.random.multinomial(1, p / p.sum(), 1)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4593, in mtrand.RandomState.multinomial (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:37541)
ValueError: sum(pvals[:-1]) > 1.0
```

How can this be?

Comment: Have you compared the values before you are passing them into `multinomial`?

Comment: The original function performs a conversion to `float64`. What datatype has `p`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My system is 64-bit, so numpy's default dtype is float64, but some of the inputs coming into this function were 32-bit floats, so somewhere in there the mixing of the two datatypes caused the error.